# postgis vs sphinx geodist

Tags: geocoding, sphinx, postgis

I have a table with 16 mln rows. Cities, streets, houses with their coordinates.

How best to search for objects, knowing their coordinates? PostGis or the Sphinx with [GeoDist](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#expr-func-geodist) function?

Now I am using a Sphinx, but there is a question the relevance of the data as well as an update of all the index takes more than 4 hours, and indexing delta with following merge main takes about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly it depends on other features you require. For example if using the text query functionality of sphinx, then stick with it.

But if not using that anyway, and can benefit of other features of postgis, then change to that.

> indexing delta with following merge main

Why merge?

Skip the merge, and just query both indexes.

Comment: if you do not merge, the deleted items will be in output.

Comment: it works only after merge.

But I'm asking quite different.